# Methods for producting alternating TickLabels in a Plot?

Tags: plotting, ticks, labeling

I am producing a plot with alternating TickLabels. Here is a MWE:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 4},
Ticks -> (Table[{i, If[EvenQ[i], 1, 2]}, {i, Ceiling[#1], Floor[#2]}] &)]
```

Is there a shorter way to achieve this effect, perhaps using keywords like `Automatic`?

Comment: That looks good to me except that I would have used `1 + Mod[i, 2]` instead of the `If` statement.

Comment: Sounds good (by the way, I can't use this particular trick in my code, because the alternating expressions are more complicated than just 1, 2).

Comment: Fair enough.  Sorry I don't have anything better for you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Still no better ticks handling, bug-free grid layouts etc... I suppose it is because no one is using this when *twitting the code*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the tick labels `{1,2}`, you can save a few key strokes using

```
{#, 1 + Mod[#, 2]}&/@Range[Ceiling@#, Floor@#2]&
(* or  {#, 1 + Mod[#, 2]}&/@Range[Ceiling@#, #2]&  -- thanks: @SimonWoods *)
```

or

```
Array[{#, 1 + Mod[#, 2]}&, ## & @@ Ceiling@{#2, #}]&
```

For arbitrary pairs of labels, you can define a tick function that takes a label list as argument:

```
tF[l_] := Array[{#, l[[Mod[#, 2, 1]]]} &, ## & @@ Ceiling @ {#2, #}] &;

Plot[x, {x, 0, 5.}, Ticks -> tF[{2, 1}]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[2 x, {x, 0, 4}, 
 Ticks -> {tF[Rotate[Style[#, Red, 16], Pi/6] & /@ {"label1", "label2"}], tF[{2, 1}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: You could save a few more keystrokes by omitting `Floor` from your first method

Comment: Good point; thank you @Simon.